# Is Hijab required in front of blind men?

Tags: fiqh, hijab, men-women, non-mahram

According to Islamic rules, is it required for a woman to wear the headscarf in the presence of a non-Mahram blind man?

Comment: i saw a video about how blind people just can't see the image because for many reasons, the brain dosen't send the signal to the eyes, but the brain can still react to the picture such as getting happy, sad and even attracted

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSf8i8bHIns here it is!

Comment: @NesreenA even if true, that would still depend hugely on the cause of blindness.

Comment: yes but im pointing out a possible situation some people would simply say he cannot see therfore its okay, but its more complex than that

Comment: It is not, to avoid duplicating the answer, I'll link you to it: http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25111/12537

Answer (score 7):

(Shia view)

According to [Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) of [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) it is not obligatory. (Considering there is no other sin). But it is recommended According to a Hadith about prophet and his daughter:

> "Once a blind man asked for permission to enter Fatima's (Her
>   Holiness) house but she kept a veil between them. The Messenger of
>   Allah (SAWS) noticed her (Our Lady Fatimah (SWT)) actions and asked:
>   Why did you (Her Holiness (SWT)) keep a veil between you (Her Holiness
>   (SWT)) when he cannot see you?" Her Holiness Fatimah (SWT) answered:
>   Messanger of Allah, it is true that he cannot see me (Her Holiness
>   (SWT)), but I (Her Holiness (SWT)) can see him and he can smell my
>   (Her Holiness (SWT)) fragrance.' At this, the Prophet (SAWS) said: "I
>   bear witness that you are part of me". (Book `Fatimah the Gracious' Pg
>   187)

---

**References:**

- [Online answering](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/?p=oas) of [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem
  Shirazi](http://www.makarem.ir/)
- http://ziaraat.org/fatima.php
- http://www.imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=6267

Comment: AFAIK This is Sunni view too

Answer (score 5):

Umm Salamah (radiallahu anhaa), the mother of the believers (wife of Rasulullah), narrates (emphasis mine):

> I was with the Messenger of Allah (salallahu alayhi wa sallam) along with Maimunah (May Allah be
>   pleased with him) when **Ibn Umm Maktum** (May Allah be pleased with him)
>   (who was blind) came to visit him. **(This incident took place after the
>   order of Hijab)**. The Prophet (salallahu alayhi wa sallam) told us to hide ourselves from him
>   (i.e., observe Hijab). We said: "O Messenger of Allah (salallahu alayhi wa sallam), he is blind
>   and is unable to see us, nor does he know us." He replied; **"Are you
>   also blind and unable to see him?"** ([Riyad As-Saliheen](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18#116); from Abu
>   Dawud and At-Tirmidhi's collections)

In this hadith, Abdullah Ibn Umm Maktoom (radiallahu anhu) came to visit Rasulullah. Abdullah ibn Umm Maktoom is none other than *the same sahabi mentioned in Surah Abasa.* From the tafseer of that great surah, we know that he was a3maa, or *blind from birth.*

In this case, the wives of the Prophet (may Allah be pleased with them) did not wear hijab at this time. The hadith mentions that `this took place after the order of Hijab.` And in this case, Rasulullah rebuked them for not wearing hijab in front of him, although he was blind.

From this hadith, and other proofs, scholars mention that it is absolutely required for a woman to wear hijab in front of a non-mahram, even if he is blind.

*And Allah knows best.*

Comment: because end of your answer contains an Fiqhi Fatwa it is better to mention the name of scholar and school and official text of fatwa with reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam-o-alaikom-va-rahmat-o-Allah-e-va-Barakatoh

She doesn't need to but she may. An example exists in the history of Islam when a blind person came to the Prophet (S.A.)'s or Hazrat Fatimeh (S.A.)'s house and she left the room or wore her Hijab (sorry, I have read that some years ago and don't remember the exact details), that's the place the Prophet (S.A.) says about her that she is a part of me, who bothers her has bothered me and who bothers me has bothered Allah, if my memory helps.

*Godspeed*

Comment: Welcome to SE.Islam. Here we usually required references if you are referring to a story/event. Answer without references are strongly discouraged. The SE rules for a good answer apply here by the way. Thank you